# Magento2 Order Number different in REST API orders

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I've changed my order number to 2000.

```
INSERT INTO magento.sequence_order_1 (sequence_value) VALUES ('2000');
```

Then change lenght of order number

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Sequence\SequenceInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string">%s%'.05d%s</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

Next orders in admin panel are correct. But when I want watch this order in REST API order is different.

```
https://www.mysite.pl/rest/V1/orders/000001
```

When I try use

```
https://www.mysite.pl/rest/V1/orders/2000
```

or

```
https://www.mysite.pl/rest/V1/orders/002000
```

And did not work. So I assume that REST API has own increment_id. Can we synchronize or change it like order number ?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correct, in API you should use order id, not order increment id. Order ID is different, you can see it in admin, when edit order in url, or look in database.